# Any advantages in terms of our location & East-West timing differences for self mining on a 100 th/s btc rig

Tags: performance, time

I do live in india.. I believe that bitcoin mining rig owners are very lessaound us ..I read some where that  we will be able to mine more bitcoins  while the west or far-east  sleeps..

Answer (score 1):

What you read is not accurate.  There is no significant difference in mining performance depending on your location.

First of all, as far as I know, the vast majority of miners run their equipment 24 hours a day (since leaving them idle just wastes the investment in hardware), so time zone differences are irrelevant.

Also, to first order, your chances of mining a Bitcoin block depend only on your hash rate and the network difficulty; it makes no difference what other miners are doing at that moment.  So even if the rest of the world quit mining completely for several hours, it wouldn't help you at all.

Of course, the network difficulty is determined indirectly by how much mining is being done around the world, but the difficulty is adjusted only once every 14 days or so (2016 blocks), so variations over the course of a day would average out.

There is actually a very slight disadvantage in being in a part of the world that has relatively few miners.  Suppose, for example, that most miners are in New York and a few are in Bombay.  If New York-based Miner A finds a block (say at height 12345) and announces it on the network, New York miners will know about it quickly, while it will take a few tens or hundreds of milliseconds to propagate across the Internet to Bombay.  During this short time, Bombay miners are at a disadvantage.  If Miner B in New York and Miner C in Bombay both find blocks during this window, B's will be linked back to A's block, whereas C's will be linked to the block before A's.  Thus B's block is part of the longer chain and will be accepted by the network, while C's will be orphaned.     But since this window would be less than a second for each block, which happens roughly every 10 minutes (600 seconds) on average, the disadavantage is at most a couple tenths of a percent.

The most important way that your location would impact your mining profitability is your local cost for electricity.